# Abort test after invisibility of element in Java Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I have a following situation in my test cases:
I want to abort test after my element is invisible on page, how to do that?
I can use try catch, but there's any built-in function to stop the test and go to the next TC?

Answer (score 0):

After asking the driver for the Element you get a WebElement and you can ask the Element if it is Displayed:

```
HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();
WebElement findElement = driver.findElement( /* enter By-here */ );
assertTrue( findElement.isDisplayed() );
```

Comment: But in this case, i will get failed test. I need passed while element is invisible

Comment: If you want the test to pass only when the element is Invisible, simply use assertFalse insted of assertTrue